# Get second occurrence from second row

Tags: regex, find-occurrences

I have the following tables from a `dotnet test` command result, and what I am trying to achieve is getting the second occurrence (the ones below **Branch**) of lines that start with **Average**.

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         | Line      | Branch    | Method    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Total   | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Average | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      | 
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         | Line      | Branch    | Method    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Total   | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Average | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      | 
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have managed writing the following regex `^\| Average *\| (\d+.\d+\%).*$` but adding `{2}` anywhere inside the expression still doesn't return me the second occurrence. Also, I've tried using https://regex101.com/ but the match information that it shows is the following:

[image: Regex101.com Match Information]

From my understanding I need to get the second group but I think I need a hint or a little bit of help to reach my goal.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you just need to get the second match (and group 1 inside that match).

Comment: Exactly. I want the second match/occurrence of 100% to be more precise. But I cannot understand why {2} wouldn't do the job :-??

Comment: Where are you trying to add the `{2}`?

Comment: I'm trying to add the `{2}` like this `^\| Average *\| (\d+.\d+\%).*{2}$`

Comment: Ah ok, in your case you don't need to modify the regex, you need to find matches, then retrieve only the second one. On regex101, you can click on "code generator" -> "python" you'll see an example of how to get matches/groups. Basically you'll use `re.finditer` then iterate over the `matches` (I'm using the variable name regex101 is using in this case).

Comment: But can't I do this in regex directly? Because this line of code I am passing it into GitLab Test Coverage Parsing to get my Code Coverage result :))

Comment: In that case it's a bit more complex and you'll need to do two things 1) make your regex cover several lines (I don't remember the option, maybe "\s"), 2) find an occurence of you pattern that is preceded by another occurence of the same pattern. At least that's the only solution I see.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
string table =
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "|         | Line      | Branch    | Method    |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "| Total   | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "| Average | 100%      |  89%      | 100%      |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "|         | Line      | Branch    | Method    |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "| Total   | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+" + Environment.NewLine +
    "| Average | 100%      | 99%       | 100%      |" + Environment.NewLine +
    "+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(table, @"(?<=\| Average *\| \d+\% +\| *)\d+\%(?=.*)");

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Outputs:

```
89%
99%
```

---

Update:

I had to find out that .NET (where I built my RegEx) supports quantifiers in lookaround expressions, while other RegEx implementations lack this support.

Therefore the RegEx expression of my solution won't run there.

To solve this, I removed the quantifiers and replaced them with fixed character declarations. This works for a fixed table, but won't work if the layout of the table is dynamic in its width:

```
(?<=\| Average \| ..\d\%      \| )\d+\%(?=.*)
```

Comment: It seems like the OP have no control over match iterations, he only has control over  the regex and the capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I see is to have a regex that will capture several lines, starting with the first "Average" and ending with the second. As for having all the logic contained in the regex, you then need to know how to specify search the options within your regex, this is usually done using `/sm`. In the end your regex would look like this:

```
/^\| Average *\| \d*.\d+\%.*$.*^\| Average *\| (\d*.\d+\%).*$/sm
```

The captured group only contains the second occurence of `Average`'s `Line` percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I got the answer by trial and error.

```
\| Average \| .*\d+\% +\| *(\d*.\d\%) +\| +\d
```

will math the column below Branches. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: What was the problem with my solution?

Comment: First, as @cglacet pointed out, I was looking for a pure regex. I took only the regex you mentioned in your answer `(?<=\| Average *\| \d+\% +\| *)\d+\%(?=.*)`, tested it with rubular.com and regex101.com but it didn't work.

Comment: ok I see: .NET supports quantifiers in lookaround expressions, while other RegEx implementations seem to not support them. This was an easy fix though: `(?<=\| Average \| ..\d\%      \| )\d+\%(?=.*)` - see: https://regex101.com/r/d7TNF9/1

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks a lot! ^_^

Comment: np, was fun to build these RegEx's and the mentioned limitation was new to me, so this is a valuable benefit! ;-)

Comment: Just had a look at your RegEx and am afraid to tell you that it doesn't work for result values other than `100%`! It is the last thing on earth I wanna do, but in the order of destiny I have to tell you that it may eventually be possible that your work results in values `<100%` there... :/ ... but don't panic, it happened that I simplified your RegEx and fixed it to support arbitrary values at any position: `\| Average \| .*\d+\% +\| +(\d+\%) +\| +\d`

Comment: I think you mean this `\| Average \| .*\d+\% +\| +(\d*.\d\%) +\| +\d` 'cause it also captures results like `19.2%` not just integer numbers. But thank for pointing this out.